# revert git commit in long running branch

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging, git-reset, git-revert

I have a 3 branches from 3 people working on 3 features. Let say my branch is named `branch-A`, and there are 2 other branches named `branch-B` and `branch-C`.

This is what happened in `branch-A`:

```
<hash-A-001> add commit for feature 1
<hash-A-002> add more commit for feature 1
<hash-A-003> add more commit for feature 1 (push to remote)
<hash-A-004> (accidentally!!!) merge master branch (contains commits and changes)
<hash-A-005> merge from branch-B (with a lot of commits and changes)
<hash-A-006> merge from branch-C (with a lot of commits and changes)
<hash-A-007> reset hash-A-004 because it is accidental merge
<hash-A-008> add more commit for feature 1
<hash-A-009> add more commit for feature 1
...
...
<hash-A-0020> add more commit for feature 1
```

Now at the point in `<hash-A-0020>`, I just realized that commit from `<hash-A-005>` and `<hash-A-006>` gone because what I've done in `<hash-A-007>` (which is, reseting commit `<hash-A-004>`). Thus all changes and features developed in `branch-B` and `branch-C` is not exist in my branch (`branch-A`).

My question is, what should I do to make sure that:

1. Files, changes and commits caused by `hash-A-004 ((accidentally!!!) merge master branch)` removed from my branch.
2. I want to keep changes and commit from `<hash-A-005> (merge from branch-B)` and `<hash-A-006> merge from branch-C` as well as commit from `hash-A-008` to `hash-A-020` in my branch. (Basically, preserve all commits except `hash-A-004` whenever possible)

?

I was thinking `git revert <hash-A-004>`, but I want to make sure that I'm not messing up more by doing wrong action not missing anything from `branch-B` and `branch-C`.

Some additional information:

1. This is long running branch, so `<hash-A-004>` to `hash-A-007` was happened like 2 or 3 weeks ago.
2. I actually not sure what was command I issued when performing `<hash-A-007>`. Either `git revert ....` or `git reset --hard`. But I think it was `reset` command since I thought there's no other commits after my accidental merge.
3. `branch-B` and `branch-C` is not available anymore, either locally or in remote repository. But it is already merged in `master` branch, in the same point when it merged with `branch-A`.

Comment: You can verify whether you used `git revert ...` or `git reset --hard` when performing `hash-A-007` by looking through the `git log` for branch A.

If you did `git reset --hard`, `hash-A-005` and `hash-A-006` will not show up in the git log.

If you did `git revert`, they will still be there.

Comment: It would be helpful to answer this question because if you did `git revert`, then everything is fine and nothing more needs to be done.

Comment: @ack_inc I think it was `git reset`. because after all, my team mate tell me in code review that there's file that should not looks like what it is now. A method missing one argument. 

Now this is easy fix if that is the only file that I need to take care of. I checked that there's a lot of files in `hash-A-005` and `hash-A-006`.